# Use comma separated input as arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, input, sympy

I have the following code for integration and differentiation with `sympy`:

```
from sympy import *
x = symbols('x')
mode = input("Differentiate (1) or Integrate (2)?\t")
function = input("Function:\t")
parameter = input("With respect to:\t")

if mode == str(1):
    deriv = diff(function, parameter)
    print(deriv)
if mode == str(2):
    intg = integrate(function, parameter)
    print(intg)
```

I want to use the input from `parameter` in the differentiate function, which can be used like that:

```
diff(exp(x*y*z), x, y, z)
```

which would give you `(x**2*y**2*z**2 + 3*x*y*z + 1)*exp(x*y*z)`.
The code works fine as long as I put in something like `x, 2`, which would be the second derivative with respect to x of the function. If the user input is `x, y, z` for example it doesn't work like shown above, but gives this error:

```
  File "/home/username/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sympy/core/function.py", line 1337, in __new__
    v, count = v

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Is there any way to use the input if it's comma seperated values as arguments? I tried splitting it but then it's a list and every letter is a string, which of course doesnt't work as an argument.

Comment: which line raises that error?

Comment: Im not sure i understood correctly, but try `deriv = diff(function, *parameter.split(','))`  This will split by commas then send each item as a parameter to the function instead of an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ron Serruyas answer worked.

```
deriv = diff(function, *parameter.split(','))
intg = integrate(function, *parameter.split(','))
```

splits the input and doesn't treat it as strings anymore.